# Positioned absolute div not appearing where defined

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet:

```css
.right_full_navigation{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width:250px; 
}
.favourites{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    right:0px;
    border-radius:7px;
    border: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    padding-top:19px;
    margin-left:6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_full_navigation">
    <div class="favourites"></div>
</div>
```

With this code, I expect the div to be located on the right side of the page, however, the div is appearing near the left hand side, floating between the middle and left side of the page. I have the exact same code on my other .php pages, but the div seems to go haywire on this page only. Is the code faulty, or is it influenced by other divs?

Comment: `position: absolute;` on a div inside a `position: relative;` div means the child will be absolute with respect to the parent div's location, *not* with respect to the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you position a parent element as `relative` and position a child as `absolute`, the position of the child is defined within the parent. So, in your instance your parent has a width of 500px. If you position the child with `right:0;`, the right side of it will butt up against the 500px width of the parent.

If you want the child element to position relative to the body instead of the parent, it has to be taken out of the parent, or, the position of the parent should be set to `static`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set parent DIV (right_full_navigation) width only 250px and also used same width for child div (favourites).

Just increase the parent div width or set parent width (100%).
Hope it'll work.

```css
.right_full_navigation{
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width:100%; 
}
.favourites{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    right:0px;
    border-radius:7px;
    border: 1px solid #E1E3E4;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:250px;
    height:500px;
    padding-top:19px;
    margin-left:6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_full_navigation">
    <div class="favourites"></div>
</div>
```